# use x-displayName to show name with spaces in open_api.yaml

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

Here is a snippet of our **open_api.yaml**, with the correct indentations:

```
tags:
    - name: Team-Game-Stats
      x-displayName: Team Game Stats
      description: Team game statistics derived from box score data

paths:
    /stats/team/game-box:
        get:
            tags:
                - Team-Game-Stats
            parameters:
                ...
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: successful operation
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                type: array
                                items:
                                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Team-Game-Stats'

components:
    schemas:
        Team-Game-Stats:
            x-displayName: Team Game Stats
            type: object
```

And here is how this looks on the website docs:

[image]

Our goal is to show `Team Game Stats` rather than `Team-Game-Stats` on the website. We thought `x-displayName` would achieve this, but it is clearly not. It seems like spaces are not allowed in the `tags` or `schemas` of an **open_api.yaml** file.

Is it possible to update our **open_api.yaml** so that `Team Game Stats` is displayed in the text, even though `Team-Game-Stats` is used in the tag and the schema?

**Edit:** It seems like we can in-fact add spaces to the tag name, **HOWEVER** then the anchor-link part of the URL become wonky looking, with `%20` in place of the spaces. If we click on Team-Game-Stats, the URL updates to `http://localhost:8080/api-docs/#/Team%20Game%20Stats` which is messier and less preferred than something like `http://localhost:8080/api-docs/#/Team-Game-Stats`.

We are looking for a solution where we can have both (i) spaces in the name of the endpoints on the website, as well as (ii) no `%20`s in the anchor links when the endpoint is clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

> We thought `x-displayName` would achieve this, but it is clearly not.

Swagger UI does not support `x-displayName`, unless you use a custom fork or plugin that implements support for this extension.

For schemas, you can use the `title` attribute. If it's present, Swagger UI uses it as a display name for the schema:

```yaml
components:
    schemas:
        Team-Game-Stats:
            title: Team Game Stats
            type: object
```

Tags don't have a display name. You have several options:

- Change the tag names in your original OpenAPI definition.
- Create a copy of your OpenAPI definition with the updated tag names (e.g. write a script that would update the tag names) and use that copy with Swagger UI.
- Write a Swagger UI plugin that would mutate the tag names on-the-fly. Check out [this sample plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5981) to get an idea of how to mutate fields in an OpenAPI definition after it's loaded into Swagger UI.

Comment: Good information, thanks for letting me know. Creating a swagger UI plugin is a bit outside what I'm comfortable or familiar with. At least initially, we will probably simply use the tag names with spaces and live with `%20`s in the anchor links.